# Navigation to another page and showing a bookmark/id there, while hiding others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code to show some hidden Bootstrap `wells` on same pages when a menu item is clicked (works like tabbed content shower). It is working fine, but I want to be able to use it to go to other pages and show a well (based on `id` attribute there. Its not working that way, please help.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var navItems = $('.menu-level-2 li > a');
    var navListItems = $('.menu-level-2 li');
    var allWells = $('.menu-level-2-content');
    var allWellsExceptFirst = $('.menu-level-2-content:not(:first)');

    allWellsExceptFirst.hide();
    navItems.click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        navListItems.removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

        allWells.hide();
        var target = $(this).attr('data-target-id');
        $('#' + target).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post your html ?

Comment: You need to make your jquery code persist in some way so that when the new page is opened the last actions that should be applied to this newly loaded page should be applied onload of that page.

You can use `localStorage.setItem('yourKey', 'YourValue');` to set certain flags and then check on the newly loaded page with `localStorage.getItem('yourKey');`

Answer (score 0):

The question is not fully clear to me, but if you want to go to another page (when clicked on navigation), and on that another page, you want to automatically show that tabbed content, then you should do like this:

```
navItems.click(function(e)
{
    ..........
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target-id');
    window.location='http://example.com/mypage.php#requested_id='+target;
});
```

and on the target **mypage.php**, you should have javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if (window.location.hash){
       .....
       allWells.hide();
       $('#' + window.location.hash).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what I need to add in places where you placed "......". I am very new to all this.

Originally, I am having following problem; the JS code shows one specific well (all others are hidden by default) on the same page when a navigation is clicked, another well is shown when another navigation item is clicked. What I want to achieve is that I want to place the navigation items on one page and the wells on another, so when navigation is click another page is loaded with the respective well shown.